# Nativescript android app crashes after 3 minutes

Tags: android, nativescript

I am developing an app using {N} 2.0.1
However when I run the app on the android emulator (geny motion) , after a couple of minutes , it just crashes with this stack trace :

```
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
I/dalvikvm( 5042):   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
```

Interesetingly I have observed this behavior only on android simulator. On iOS simulator or android physical device,  I have not encountered it.
Is this something related to the emulator or is a piece of my code causing this?
If anyone has had this error before, some insight would be great!

**EDIT**

The error occurs even on android emulator.
Specifically it happens after I navigate to my custom tab view implementation.
Here is how I've implemented it
main.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="loaded" 
xmlns:t1="partial-views/explore"
xmlns:t2="partial-views/community">
<ActionBar title="Haloose">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout   verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" id="sl_main">
    <t1:explore     id="explore"    visibility="{{ currentActive == 'explore' ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />
    <t2:community   id="community"  visibility="{{ currentActive == 'community' ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"/> />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout id="sl_menu" orientation="horizontal">
        <Image src="{{ currentActive == 'explore' ? '~/img/icon-green/icon-explore.png' : '~/img/icon-gray/icon-explore.png' }}" class="menuimage" tap="loadexplore"/>
        <Image src="{{ currentActive == 'community' ? '~/img/icon-green/icon-community.png' : '~/img/icon-gray/icon-community.png' }}" class="menuimage" tap="loadcommunity"/>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

And here is the output seen from android device monitor

```
05-25 09:50:53.188: D/dalvikvm(2170): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1309K, 5% free 31388K/32812K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
05-25 09:50:53.198: A/libc(2170): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=128), thread 2170 (escript.haloose)
05-25 09:50:53.298: I/DEBUG(1122): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-25 09:50:53.298: I/DEBUG(1122): Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.2/KK/2872501:eng/test-keys'
05-25 09:50:53.298: I/DEBUG(1122): Revision: '0'
05-25 09:50:53.298: I/DEBUG(1122): pid: 2170, tid: 2170, name: escript.haloose  >>> org.nativescript.haloose <<<
05-25 09:50:53.298: I/DEBUG(1122): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 128 (SI_KERNEL), fault addr 00000000
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     eax b89d52e0  ebx a72d0cbc  ecx 000003fc  edx b8497b68
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     esi b8496b70  edi 000003fe
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     eip a6c398e9  ebp b8497b68  esp bfb2402c  flags 00210282
05-25 09:50:53.528: E/Corkscrew(1122): unrecognized dwarf higher part encoding: 0xeb
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122): backtrace:
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     #00  pc 0038f8e9  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::HandleScope::DeleteExtensions(v8::internal::Isolate*)+265)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     #01  pc 002a3086  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()+70)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     #02  pc 0024a377  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (Java_com_tns_Runtime_callJSMethodNative+231)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122): stack:
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb23fec  b846b6c0  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb23ff0  bfb23fe7  [stack]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb23ff4  bfb23fe0  [stack]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb23ff8  a705c4d4  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::base::Thread::SetThreadLocal(int, void*)+36)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb23ffc  0000001a  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24000  b8471e40  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24004  a72d0cbc  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24008  a6d2c1a4  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Isolate::FindOrAllocatePerThreadDataForThisThread()+116)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb2400c  a72d531c  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24010  a705c4b6  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::base::Thread::SetThreadLocal(int, void*)+6)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24014  a72d0cbc  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24018  a6d2c47c  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Isolate::SetIsolateThreadLocals(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Isolate::PerIsolateThreadData*)+60)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb2401c  0000001a  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24020  b8471e40  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24024  a6d2c139  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Isolate::FindOrAllocatePerThreadDataForThisThread()+9)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24028  a72d0cbc  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     #00  bfb2402c  b89d52e0  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24030  a6d2c446  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Isolate::SetIsolateThreadLocals(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Isolate::PerIsolateThreadData*)+6)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24034  a72d0cbc  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24038  a6d2d876  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Isolate::Enter()+118)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb2403c  00000000  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24040  b8471e40  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24044  30b7d555  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24048  00000000  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb2404c  30b88b9d  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24050  b8478a40  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24054  000003fc  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24058  00000000  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb2405c  a72d0cbc  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24060  b846b6c0  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24064  a6c397e9  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::HandleScope::DeleteExtensions(v8::internal::Isolate*)+9)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24068  a72d0cbc  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          ........  ........
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):     #01  bfb2407c  b846b6c0  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24080  a6e07d47  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::Runtime_DebugPopPromise(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)+7)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24084  a6af8f31  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (tns::Runtime::CallJSMethodNative(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, _jstring*, int, unsigned char, _jobjectArray*)+17)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24088  a6b4d048  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()+8)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb2408c  a72d0cbc  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24090  d1800035  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24094  b846b6c0  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb24098  a6af4378  /data/app-lib/org.nativescript.haloose-2/libNativeScript.so (Java_com_tns_Runtime_callJSMethodNative+232)
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb2409c  bfb240e8  [stack]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb240a0  b8305da0  [heap]
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb240a4  3ea00025  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb240a8  00001b0e  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb240ac  c0e00029  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb240b0  00000000  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb240b4  00000000  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122):          bfb240b8  f780002d  
05-25 09:50:53.528: I/DEBUG(1122): --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
05-25 09:50:53.608: W/ActivityManager(1545):   Force finishing activity org.nativescript.haloose/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-25 09:50:53.608: D/gralloc(1124): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
05-25 09:50:53.608: E/libEGL(1124): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-25 09:50:53.608: E/libEGL(1124): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-25 09:50:53.608: E/libEGL(1124): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-25 09:50:53.608: E/libEGL(1124): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-25 09:50:53.608: E/SurfaceFlinger(1124): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 2073286530
05-25 09:50:53.608: E/SurfaceFlinger(1124): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
05-25 09:50:53.608: E/libEGL(1124): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-25 09:50:53.608: E/libEGL(1124): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-25 09:50:53.618: W/WindowManager(1545): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (328x546) to layer 21010
05-25 09:50:53.628: D/Zygote(1125): Process 2170 terminated by signal (11)
05-25 09:50:53.628: W/InputDispatcher(1545): channel 'b12805d0 org.nativescript.haloose/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0xd
05-25 09:50:53.638: E/InputDispatcher(1545): channel 'b12805d0 org.nativescript.haloose/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-25 09:50:53.638: I/ActivityManager(1545): Process org.nativescript.haloose (pid 2170) has died.
05-25 09:50:53.648: W/InputDispatcher(1545): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b12805d0 org.nativescript.haloose/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity (server)'
05-25 09:50:53.648: I/WindowState(1545): WIN DEATH: Window{b12805d0 u0 org.nativescript.haloose/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}
```

Comment: can you paste complete logs

Comment: I've given up using the emulator for NativeScript - and anything else outside "standard" Android SDK code.  I get the same intermittent type crashes using ffmpeg etc. - it seems that the emulator doesn't really support this.

Comment: Have you tried Android emulator outside genymotion? Just to discard Genymotion issues. I haven't had any issues with genymotiun and {N}2.0.1, though

Comment: @sailens ok will try with android virtual device...sigh...thanks!

Comment: @Aaron you can run the command monitor (in your cmd/shell) to start the Android Device Monitor and log more detailed information about this error. It is similar to the one described here - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/2133

Comment: @NickIliev updated the question! Thanks!

Comment: @sailens I've tried with android emulator and it crashes swell...only on physical devices it doesn't

Comment: It looks in the logs that you are trying to call a non-existing OpenGL API

Comment: @sailens And what's that? How would you access that?

Comment: @AaronUllal That is a grpahics renderer library. Besides that I have no further clue, sorry

Comment: just to share with the community - the answer to this issue is here https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2195